# How can I modify the xCode project automatic which generate by Unity?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I create a Unity project and generate an xCode project .  Aways I should and some frameworks or static libs to the xCode project to make it run .  So I want make this progress automatic.

I found some tools to modify the xCode project . such as "Mod PBXProj":
https://bitbucket.org/darktable/mod-pbxproj/src

My question is that how can I call the tools(such as "Mod PBXProj") to modify the xCode project after the Unity project generate the xCode project . Or are there any other method to modify the project?

Comment: Someone ported Mod PBXProj to C# and made it much easier to use from Unity. http://www.keepcalmandrevert.com/blog/2012/11/xcode-project-editor/

Answer (score 0):

If you will open unity application as a folder, there will be a folder of xCode project, wich unity just copies while build. you can add there any files you whant (or replace), and on every new build, unity you use modified files.